# Get app download count from Google Play Store or App Store

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, app-store-connect, google-developers-console

Are there APIs to get app download count from Google Play Store or App Store?

If not, is there a way to automatically download CSV with this information from Google Developer Console or iTunes Connect?

Comment: You should be able to generate a report from Google Play Developer's console with the above information and more.